# How do I display an error message that it couldn't find any results

Tags: php, mysql

How do I make PHP show a message that it couldn't find any results instead of it showing nothing in the results when the query couldn't find any results?

Here is my code *to show the results*:

```
  print "  <table border = '1'> \n";



  print "      <tr> \n";

  while ($field = mysqli_fetch_field($result)){

    print "        <th>$field->name</th> \n";

  } // end while

  print "      </tr> \n";



  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    print "      <tr> \n";

    foreach ($row as $name => $value){

      print "        <td>$value</td> \n";    

    } // end foreach



    print "      </tr> \n";



  } // end while loop



  print "    </table> \n";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mysqli_num_rows() you can count the number of rows having data in the table.

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row_cnt > 0){
  //data exist for it 
}else{
  //Display your error message here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry about the bad research I did.  You can close this if you want.